# How to limit length of inner divs inside another div using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

like

```
    <div class="a">
    <div class="a1"></div>
    <div class="a2"></div>
    <div class="a3"></div>
    <div class="a4"></div>
    <div class="a5"></div>
    <div class="a6"></div>
    <div class="a7"></div>
    <div class="a8"></div>
    </div>
```

i need to limit the length of div 'a' to 4 using jquery.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by _limit the length_? and what you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove them all:

```
$(".a4").nextAll().remove();
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mYc4a/1/

Or even:

```
$(".a > *:eq(3)").nextAll().remove();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mYc4a/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.a').find('div:gt(3)').remove();
```